# In what layer is metric gathering considered to fit on Domain Driven design?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I need to collect and export metrics from my domain. In a way, I feel like metrics are pure business based, and so, must be in domain layer. On the other hand, I am afraid to store the state of counters in domain, due to the fact that their proper state depends on transactionality

Imagine you have a typical CRUD + some minor business logic DDD app, and you want to register all creations, updates, etc.. and then export them through an endpoint. how would you design this?

Comment: What else do you have in the "etc"? Are you looking to track every event in your system or are you looking to track every database operation?

Comment: For now, just a counter of creations/updtaes, but I must expose them through an endpoint for the monitoring system to scrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution would change according to the framework and technologies you are using to implement the solution, but let me put some general guideline which are widely applicable,

When you run analytic metrics for a Domain model, it is important to understand the significance for the analytics. How often they would be accessed? Is the metrics used for audit logs or are they drive business decisions? These question should guide us to the right model to use.

When the metrics are as important as your domain you should start thinking about considering them as separate entities. They should be designed in a separate context. Metric and analytics needed are often different from traditional CRUD needs and a separate "bounded context" does makes sense here.

If you are just getting started or has limited use of analytics, you can consider having audit logs right next to the CRUD data and derive metric information every time on-demand. This would save time as you do not need to design a separate metric context.

Comment: I am thinking of a bean called MetricCollector, which is placed on domain layer and translates different business operations into internal counters. For instance, createdDomainEntity(DomainEntity) increments a counter. Later on, in the application layer, a service just triggers these methods at the end of any CRUD operation, and finally on the infrastructure layer I have a registry that binds the counters form MetricCollector bean into external interfaces for the monitoring system. Does it look suitable?

Comment: @Whimusical looks ok.